# creating JSON String

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have task that involves creating the right design for the JSON string before I can get a response from the webservice. The JSON string has to look like this:

```
{"nid":"","vocab":"", "inturl":"testoverview", "mail":"", "md5pw":""}
```

and my JSON string looks like this:

```
"nid:",
"vocab:",
"inturl:testoverview",
"mail:",
"md5pw:"
```

as you can see it's not built the same way, I'm not using braces, or separating the strings the right way. And I don't know how to do this.

my code for this is here:

```
NSString *nid = @"nid:";
NSString *vocab = @"vocab:";
NSString *inturl = @"inturl:testoverview";
NSString *mail = @"mail:";
NSString *md5pw = @"md5pw:";

NSArray *jsonArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nid, vocab, inturl, mail, md5pw, nil];
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


FSProductTestHandler *handler = [[FSProductTestHandler alloc] init];

if (!jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error; %@", error);
} else if(jsonData) {

    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *url = @"http://www.taenk.dk/services/mobile";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:30.0];

    [request setValue:jsonString forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-FBR-App"];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are feeding an array to the serialisation which means you'll get a JSON array as output i.e soemthing like:

```
[ "foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

(note the brackets `[ ...]` instead of braces `{ ... }`)

You need to build an NSDictionary and for your particular example, the quickest way is like this:

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                                @"", @"nid",
                                @"", @"vocab",
                                @"testoverview", @"inturl",
                                @"", @"md5pw", 
                                @"", @"mail",
                                nil];
```

Feed that into `NSJSONSerialization` and you'll get what you want.

Comment: That's almost right, except in the original "nib" is mapped to the empty string, not "vocab", and "vocab" is another key mapped to the empty string. Same with "md5pw" and "mail". Both are keys mapping to the empty string.

Comment: @Ken:  Thanks, I have fixed it (and changed nib to nid).

Comment: it should be like: 
`NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"", @"vocab", @"", @"nid", @"", @"testoverview", @"", @"inturl", @"", @"md5pw", @"", @"mail", nil];`
Ps. Also note it's 'nid' not 'nib'...

Comment: thanks guys, i appreciate the quick response, and will be trying it

Comment: @JeremyP You're welcome :) There is one pair still wrong though, I guess sometimes the eyes are tired :P

Comment: @JeremyP oops my bad, I guess *my* eyes are tired :P (thought that every key is mapped to an empty string)

Comment: as i have implemented the code, my string looks like this now.

{
    inturl = testoverview;
    mail = "chh@fbr.dk";
    md5pw = 4d57e7ef1b7c3f431aca424764e9d786;
    nid = "";
    vocab = "";
}

The thing is that there must not be and = but : that separates the strings. I have to create a String that is a combination of all of my parameters including the {} and : .. I am a Java man, so i dont know how to combine strings in objective-c.